# I need help finding the C-Value of the sine graph of a sinusoidal function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Here is the problem:
The population of racoons in the U District is a sinusoidal function of time. The population oscillates between 20 and 80 raccoons. In 2007, there were 50 raccons. The population then decreased, reaching a minimum of, 20 raccoons, in 2009. For how long between the years 2006 and 2015 is the population of raccoons more than 65?

So for this question, I know you can use either a cosine or a sine equation, and I would like to use the sine equation. I know that the equation goes like this:

$A \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{B}(x - c)\right) + D$

Where A is the amplitude and is calculated by $\frac{{\text{{max}} - \text{{min}}}}{2}$. So in this case it would be $\frac{{80 - 20}}{2}$ which equals 30.

The B value is the period, which is 8.

The D value is the vertical shift and is calculated by $\frac{{\text{{max}} + \text{{min}}}}{2}$. So in this case it would be $\frac{{80 + 20}}{2}$ which equals 50.

And for the C value I know that would be the horizontal shift of the graph, but I'm not sure how I would find it with the sine graph.

So currently, my equation stands as $30\sin\left(\frac{{2\pi}}{{8}}(x-c)\right)+50$.

I would appreciate any help in finding the C-Value of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

You want your function to be $20$ when $x=2009$. So you want the sine function to be $-1$, so you can take
$$
{2\pi\over8}(2009-c)=-\pi/2
$$
which you can solve to get an acceptable value of $c$.

Comment: I solved for C but i get 2011 as my C-value, but when I checked my teachers answer key, it said 5 for C

Comment: If $c=5$, then the value at $x=2009$ is $30\sin((\pi/4)2004)+50=30\sin(501\pi)+50=50$, not $20$, so $c=5$ is wrong (or else something went wrong with the formula earlier).